# How to add spacing to the image tag? [jQuery Terminal]

Tags: jquery, terminal, jquery-terminal

How can I add a spacing or tab character before an image? I am making a terminal that resembles/bears a similarity to the neofetch command, and I kinda want to imitate the color palette [like this](https://www.bleepstatic.com/content/posts/2018/12/14/neofetch-header.jpg).

I have tried the following:

```
&emsp;[[@;;;;https://placekitten.com/300/300]
&ensp;[[@;;;;https://placekitten.com/300/300]
    [[@;;;;https://placekitten.com/300/300]
\t[[@;;;;https://placekitten.com/300/300]
```

All of the code above prints the image but it is on a new line, and there is no spacing added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want such big space on the left, the best way is to use CSS as with any layout changes.

Just add a class:

```
[[@;;;space-image;https://placekitten.com/300/300]
```

and use CSS:

```cs
.space-image {
   margin-left: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works just as I want it to be.